# WiFi stops working after waking from suspend with a Broadcom 43225

Tags: wireless, suspend, broadcom

wired connection works but I am forced to reboot if I want wifi to start working again.

I have an acer one 721-3801 on 10.10. help?

I have the broadcom 43225 driver if that helps... (I am very new to ubuntu so please let me know if you need any additional info)

Answer (score 3):

What does reboot do? Stop networking-manager, unload the module, reload the module and start nm.

I'm not sure, what the module-name for your driver is. I guess b43. You could do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
sudo rmmod b43
sudo modprobe b43
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

and try if it helps.

Comment: +100 In my case the module is `iwlagn`, but when I discovered this fix I created a bash alias and now it hardly even bothers me: `alias riwl="sudo rmmod iwlagn; sudo modprobe iwlagn";`.  Haven't found that restarting network manager is necessary.

Comment: Awesome, added it to a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d and ran the lines above only on resume for my module which is wl and works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a different Wifi manager -- many people have issues (including me) with Ubuntu's default "Network Manager" and switch to [Wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/).

Did the Restricted Drivers application prompt you to install your driver or did you go to the manufacturer's website and download and install it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with my ancient (but still kicking) Comapaq r4000. What I do is this:

```
~$ sudo rmmod b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

The wifi goes away for a moment, comes back, and scans for my network. Perfect.
I keep meaning to write a script, but it's been 3 years... I don't think I'm going to. :)

Answer (score 0):

`nm-tool`

Look for the line `Driver:`

Then check to reload the driver

```
sudo rmmod (your driver)
sudo modprobe (you driver)
```

If works:

```
$ sudo  gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_wireless_sleep

#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
suspend|hibernate)
/sbin/rmmod (you driver)
 ;;
resume|thaw)
 /sbin/rmmod (you driver)
 /sbin/modprobe (you driver)
;;
esac
exit 0

sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_wireless_sleep
```

based on

[Wireless doesn't connect after suspend on an Asus K52F](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67280/wireless-doesnt-connect-after-suspend-on-an-asus-k52f)