# Wireless doesn't connect after suspend on an Asus K52F

Tags: 11.10, wireless, suspend, atheros

I'm on an ASUS K52F running Ubuntu 11.10 with the AR9285 wireless card. Wifi works acceptably before suspending, after it doesn't show any networks. the only solution I've found is a full reboot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can reload the wireless driver after suspend to avoid a reboot. My driver is 'ath9k' which you can find by running 'nm-tool' and look for the line similar to

```
Driver:   ath9k
```

Then to reload the driver:

```
sudo rmmod ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

To make this happen automatically when you come back from suspend we can add the following script at /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_wireless_sleep

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    /sbin/rmmod ath9k
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    /sbin/rmmod ath9k
    /sbin/modprobe ath9k
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Replace the "ath9k" module name with the module you discovered from the nm-tool output mentioned above. I had to name the script "00_wireless_sleep" so it gets run after all the other resume scripts (scripts get run in reverse order on resume).
Don't forget to make file "00_wireless_sleep" executable:

`sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_wireless_sleep`

Comment: Adding `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` worked for me.  [reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850627&page=2)

Comment: The issue is that if I suspend for *too long* I get these problems. Since none of the above answers work for me, here's what I do. Suspend again. Resume in 10s. Then it works.

Comment: **Note to future readers**  This answer still works(in 14.04) as of 11-25-2014.  Thanks Ryan

Answer (score 5):

I've the same problem, but with different laptop/wificard. Try to restart the network-manager service:

`sudo service network-manager restart`