# Ubuntu 12.04 HP dv7 cannot connect to wireless network after suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn’t connect after suspend on an Asus K52F](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67280/wireless-doesnt-connect-after-suspend-on-an-asus-k52f)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP dv7 laptop and every time I wake from suspend I am unable to connect to my wireless network.  Ubuntu tries to reconnect me to the network but after a period of time the window pops up asking for me to enter the network key.  I enter the network key but it still won't connect.  Where should I start looking for what could cause this problem?

Thank you very much here is some info from `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 67
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-24-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=10.0.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:c4500000-c4501fff
```

Thank you very much

Comment: As a wild guess, I'd look at the length of the IP address length in the router properties.  When you get an IP address using DHCP, there's usually a timeout for it, and if you sleep past the timeout, Ubuntu my be trying to use an expired IP address, without knowing it.  So increasing this expiration time may fix it.