# Wifi switch on after waking up from suspend

Tags: 12.04, wireless, suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn’t connect after suspend on an Asus K52F](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67280/wireless-doesnt-connect-after-suspend-on-an-asus-k52f)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspier 4752 Notebook. First it seems that the wifi was not working, but after reading some of the answers in community and trying out different things i found out that i have to press the Fn+F3+F3 :). Meaning that i had to press the F3 twice to get the wifi enabled. The first press only enabled Bluetooth. But the problem is event though the wifi is disabled (HW Switch) when the Notebook wake up from a suspend session it switch on the wifi and my wify LED starts to glow. i tried removing acer_wmi and waking up from suspend but it didn't solve the problem.

So do we have any solution for this ? Is there any way we could at least run a command to disabled this on wakeup ?

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem. So, you found any solution.

Comment: Well I blacklist Acer module from modprobe and now it will arleast enable the wifi menu so enabling and disabling cause the led to switch off. I'm looking for possibility to run a script on wake-up to automate this. Still didn't got time to search for it.