# WiFi can't connect after suspend

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, kernel, suspend

I've had this problem since Ubuntu 11.10 (my first install) but I was able to get around this issue with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/67852/58063).  After I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 I tried to use the same fix as before but I couldn't get it to work.  I've also tried a couple other different fixes I found around the web but they didn't work.

Basically here's what happens: I can see all the networks in my area.  When I try to connect to one of them it never connects, it keeps disconnecting.  After a little bit it asks for the password again but its already filled in correctly.  If I hit okay it will do the exact same thing again.

So does anyone know how I can get this fixed?

**INFO:**

```
Computer: HP Pavilion dv6t-6b00 CTO Quad Edition Entertainment Notebook PC

Network Card: Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1 (x64) dual booting with Windows 7 (x64) (*Not using Wubi*)

Wireless Card Driver: iwlwifi
```

**UPDATE:** I was about to reinstall but discovered the same issue happens on Ubuntu's live disc.  I still was unable to fix it as before.  I also tried the Xubuntu's live disc, and the same.  Re installing the driver hasn't worked either.

**UPDATE:** I just tried out OpenSUSE and I'm having the same problem on that too.  So it must be the kernel or one of it's drivers.  I've done:

```
sudo rmmod xxxxxx
sudo modprobe xxxxxx
```

with iwlwifi and the other modules it uses (cfg80211 and mac80211) when my network wasn't working and it didn't do anything.  I've made a bug [report](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/9/19/470) but I don't know if I'm gonna get a response (feels familiar).  For now though I guess I'm forced to stick with Windows and dream about Linux :(.  I'll keep looking for a way to fix it however.

Comment: You are probably right, chances are that it is a bug.  Linux has had more than a few problems with power management in the past, and no operating system is bug-free.  Did you try running `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down %% sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` after suspend?

Comment: @InkBlend: No, but I just tried now (after suspend) and it returns "%%: Unknown host"

Comment: @InkBlend, did you mean `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down | sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`?  I tried this and seemed to run the command but made no response.  It also made no effect.

Comment: When you put `&&` in-between subsequent commands in bash, it only runs the second command (you can chain them, as in `command1 && command2 && command3; command4`) if the first completes successfully.  `;`, on the other hand, runs the second command regardless of whether the first one finishes.  I don't know about `|`, as I have never encountered or used it before.

Comment: @InkBlend: Cool, that's good to know.  So what does `%%` do? Do you know why it didn't work for me?  I'm just using Ubuntu's default shell.

Comment: Public announcement to all: I messed up.  My first comment stated that you should use `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down %% sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`.  That was completely and totally wrong.  The correct command is `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`.  I don't even know what `%%` _does_.  My bad.

Comment: I recommend [ThinkPenguin's line of wireless devices](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux).  They are designed specifically for Linux, and, providing your notebook accepts their wireless cards, should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help InkBlend!  I'll see if I can get one of these cards.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed that if I suspend leaving some internet SW running (such as Firefox or Rhytmhbox listening to some internet radio) when I resume the WiFi works. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04
`sudo service network-manager restart`